# Swap content in the table list using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a list, which contains id,name,phoneno,priority,country. In the jquery, I'm displaying them in a table, using javascript. Now I want to swap the just the data in the priority column, like ex: i have

```
id  Name  phoneno priority
1   abc    234343  4
2   rgt    454444  3
3   erd    432322  1
```

The display would be like the above one using 's when i hover on the priority column, i need to swap the content 4 and 3 they have to be swapped.
How to do this? I used sortable JQuery, but as it's using `<ul><li>`, i'm using `<tr><td>`'s its not working.

Please help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: swap means? you want to sort the entire column when you click the header?

Comment: I think you want to swap to rows, but how and when? Please try to be more clear, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: No, just 2 rows, In the example above the priority column contains 4,3,1. I need to drag and drop 3 in the 1st row so that it becomes 3,4,1

Comment: I need it like this http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: you can try this demo http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/make-table-rows-sortable-using-jquery-ui-sortable to drag and drop row(Like Jquery Ui), (not table-cell).

Answer (score 0):

Check this.
http://tablesorter.com/docs/

tablesorter works on standard HTML tables. You must include THEAD and TBODY tags:

```
   <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
   <thead> 
   <tr> 
       <th>Last Name</th> 
       <th>First Name</th> 
       <th>Email</th> 
       <th>Due</th> 
       <th>Web Site</th> 
   </tr> 
   </thead> 
   <tbody> 
   <tr> 
       <td>Smith</td> 
       <td>John</td> 
       <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
       <td>$50.00</td> 
       <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
       <td>Bach</td> 
       <td>Frank</td> 
       <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
       <td>$50.00</td> 
       <td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
       <td>Doe</td> 
       <td>Jason</td> 
       <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td> 
       <td>$100.00</td> 
       <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
       <td>Conway</td> 
       <td>Tim</td> 
       <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td> 
       <td>$50.00</td> 
       <td>http://www.timconway.com</td> 
   </tr> 
   </tbody> 
   </table>
```

Start by telling tablesorter to sort your table when the document is loaded:

```
    $(document).ready(function() 
        { 
            $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
        } 
    );
```

Comment: ponja, I dont want to sort it, I want to swap it.

Comment: The above one is fine, i just want to swap the grade column, Ex: No 3 has Grade 'B' and no 4 has grade 'C' now i need to swap the grades such that no 3 has grade 'C' and no 4 has grade 'B'